# I can not Inject Spring Beans into Test using TestNG launcher (Multithreading)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, heroku, testng

```
@TransactionConfiguration
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AnyTest extends TestMachine {

    @Inject
    private AccountDao accDao; //ALLWAYS NULL
```

**I run the test with:**

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Bean
public SessionScope sessionScope(){
    return new SessionScope();
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws ConfigurationException {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws ConfigurationException {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    //DB INITIALIZE
}

@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws ConfigurationException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("package.model");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ConfigurationException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateAuto);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", showSQL);
        return properties;
    }
```

**SpringMVCInitializer.java**

```
public class SpringMVCInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {AppConfig.class, SpringMVCConfiguration.class, SimpleCORSFilter.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**Maven dependency versions:**

```
<spring-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-version>
<spring-test>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-test>
<testNG-Version>6.9.4</testNG-Version>

<hibernate.version>4.1.5.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-validator>4.2.0.Final</hibernate-validator>
<mysql.connector.version>5.1.32</mysql.connector.version>
<dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
```

Why I can't *inject* any bean to a test?

**Note**: I used @Autowired and it did not work too.

One sugestion is inject the session in the main method I used to run the test. 
Is any way to make this?

Comment: Where's your `AccountDao` bean?

Comment: Its a Repository Transactional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem creating a Static Class and injecting the dependencies into this class in a controller.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class InitController {

@Inject
public InitController(TestDao testDao, InsynctivePropertyDao propertyDao, ServletContext servletContext, AccountDao accDao, CrossBrowserAccountDao crossDao, CreatePersonFormDao createPersonFormDao, TestSuiteDao testSuiteDao) {
    HibernateUtil.init(testDao, propertyDao, servletContext, accDao, crossDao, createPersonFormDao, testSuiteDao);
}
}
```

***HibernateUtil.java***

```
public class HibernateUtil {

public static CrossBrowserAccountDao crossDao;
public static TestDao testDao;

public static synchronized void init(TestDao testDao, InsynctivePropertyDao propertyDao, ServletContext servletContext, AccountDao accDao, CrossBrowserAccountDao crossDao, CreatePersonFormDao createPersonFormDao, TestSuiteDao testSuiteDao){
    HibernateUtil.crossDao = crossDao;
    HibernateUtil.testDao = testDao;
}
}
```